# Is Android Wear 2.0's version of SimpleDateFormat broken?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, simpledateformat, android-wear-2.0

I updated to Android Wear 2.0 today. My watch face, developed by myself, now shows `", 005 14"`. Before the update, it had said `"Sun, May 14"`.

The code which gets the date format:

```
    String pattern = android.text.format.DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(locale, "EEEddMMM");

    delegate = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    delegate.setCalendar(calendar);
```

From debugging, the value it fetched was `"EEE, MMM dd"`.

The code which does the actual formatting:

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, time.getDayOfWeek() + 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, time.getDayOfMonth());
    // Android hard-codes in a + 1 when formatting as a number.
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, time.getMonthOfYear() - 1);
    return delegate.format(dummyDate);
```

I checked the [current docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `SimpleDateFormat` and both `E` and `M` are still supposedly supported. So is Wear 2.0 just broken?

I figure for later API versions it might be possible to work around this by using the `android.icu` alternative. But this means supporting both the old and new code indefinitely, so if it turns out that it's something they're planning to fix in the platform, I'd rather not waste any more time.

Comment: Crappily, it seems that after further investigation, the answer is yes, the platform's SimpleDateFormat is now broken. I filed [a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38289595) but I'll keep the question around and either a nice workaround will appear, or I will answer it myself.

Comment: Thanks for filing this as a bug. For a workaround, you could use `DateFormat.format(pattern, calendar)` - I'm successfully using this on both Wear 1.x and 2.0.

Comment: I had tried DateFormat.format previously and found that my unit tests failed because Android was stubbing out all the method implementations to return null. :/